# var_dump present values but cant call them

Tags: php, google-api

I’m using Google's Analytics API with the GAPI interface and find a difficult to get results for a query.

From `print_r($resultsTotal)` I get the following.

```
 Array
(
[0] => gapiReportEntry Object
    (
        [metrics:private] => Array
            (
                [avgTimeOnSite] => 102.38
                [pageviewsPerVisit] => 1.9
                [pageValue] => 0
                [visitBounceRate] => 72
            )

        [dimensions:private] => Array
            (
                [hostname] => www.dossihost.net
            )

    )

)
```

From using `var_dump($resultsTotal)` I get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(gapiReportEntry)#2 (2) { ["metrics:private"]=> array(4) { ["avgTimeOnSite"]=> float(102.38) ["pageviewsPerVisit"]=> float(1.9) ["pageValue"]=> float(0) ["visitBounceRate"]=> float(72) } ["dimensions:private"]=> array(1) { ["hostname"]=> string(17) "www.dossihost.net" } } }
```

But when request it via this way:

```
echo '<div><span>Avg TimeOnSite</span><br />'.$resultsTotal->getavgTimeOnSite().'</div>';
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getavgTimeOnSite() on a non-object in /home/workprog/public_html/gapi-1.3/test.php on line 80
```

Comment: where is this `getavgTimeOnSite()` function defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your structure you have an array with objects. Also it seems like `getavgTimeOnSite()` is a utility method that accesses the data? So your `array` and `object` data doesn’t really help debug much. Well, other than letting me know there is an `array` with an `object` in it! So perhaps you can access the data like this:

```
echo '<div><span>Avg TimeOnSite</span><br />' . $resultsTotal[0]->getavgTimeOnSite() . '</div>';
```

Or even roll through the array with a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($resultsTotal as $result) {
    echo '<div><span>Avg TimeOnSite</span><br />' . $result->getavgTimeOnSite() . '</div>';
}
```

I also [found this source code for a project](https://github.com/electricg/Google-Analytics-Report/blob/master/import_data.php) that shows how the developer is accessing data in Google Analytics requests. Check it out to get more insights into how to access data.